# Check if two checkboxes are unchecked and disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to disable a button when 1 or both checkboxes are unchecked, so only enable it when both checkboxes are checked.

The checkboxes are added after pageload so my code currently looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('change','#voorwaarden', function() {
    jQuery("#checkoutbtn").prop('disabled', !this.checked)
    });
```

And my html:

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" disabled="disabled" class="button btn-checkout" id="checkoutbtn" onclick="review.save();"><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></button>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="voorwaarden" style="display:inline;" required/><b> Ik ga akkoord met de algemene voorwaarden <em>*</em></b></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="geboorte" style="display:inline;"/><b> Ik ben ouder dan 18 jaar <em>*</em></b></p>
```

One more issue, I want to show an alert when the button is clicked and when it's disabled but I see that a click function cannot be fired on a disabled button.

Currently it only enables the button when `#voorwaarden` is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like that

```js
$(document).on('change','.chk', function() {
    var checkCount=$('.chk:checked').length;
    var totalCheckbox =$('.chk').length;
    totalCheckbox==checkCount ? $("#checkoutbtn").prop('disabled', false):$("#checkoutbtn").prop('disabled', true);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" disabled="disabled" class="button btn-checkout" id="checkoutbtn" onclick="review.save();"><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></button>
 <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox chk" id="voorwaarden" style="display:inline;" required/><b> Ik ga akkoord met de algemene voorwaarden <em>*</em></b></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox chk" id="geboorte" style="display:inline;"/><b> Ik ben ouder dan 18 jaar <em>*</em></b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. The button is enabled only when the two checkboxes are checked.

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.checkbox', function () {
 var bflag = true;
 jQuery(".checkbox").each(function (i, e) {
  if ($(this).is(":checked") == false) bflag = false;    
 })
 jQuery("#checkoutbtn").prop('disabled', !bflag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" title="Submit" disabled="disabled" class="button btn-checkout" id="checkoutbtn" onclick="review.save();"><span>test</span></button>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="voorwaarden" style="display:inline;" required/><b> Ik ga akkoord met de algemene voorwaarden <em>*</em></b></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="geboorte" style="display:inline;" /><b> Ik ben ouder dan 18 jaar <em>*</em></b></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the disabled button, the browser literally doesn't know the button got clicked, nor does it pass the click event on. So it is impossible to give an alert when click on disable button. SO you try the below code.

**Your HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="button btn-checkout" id="checkoutbtn">
<span>Submit</span></button>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="voorwaarden" 
style="display:inline;" required/><b> Ik ga akkoord met de algemene 
voorwaarden <em>*</em></b></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="geboorte" 
style="display:inline;"/><b> Ik ben ouder dan 18 jaar <em>*</em></b></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#checkoutbtn").click(function () {

    if($('#voorwaarden').is(':checked') && $('#geboorte').is(':checked'))                   {
            alert("Your Success Message");
      return true;
    }
else{
            alert("Your Fail Message");
      return false;
        }            

     });
```

You can see the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sasirekha_ch/eby6ernh/) here

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try:

```
$('#voorwaarden').click(function(){

if($(this).attr('checked') == false){
     $('#checkoutbtn').attr("disabled","disabled");   
}
else {
    $('#checkoutbtn').removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '#voorwaarden,#geboorte', function(){
    console.log($('#voorwaarden:checked,#geboorte:checked').length);
    if($('#voorwaarden:checked, #geboorte:checked').length == 2)
        $('button').removeAttr("disabled");
    else $('button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });

  $('button').click(function(e){
    alert('test');
  })
});
```

This code does what you need, but with one exception - disabled element doesn't fire events.

Answer (score 0):

If both checkboxs are `checked` then button should be accessible, else it should be `disabled`! Then below snippet will help to achieve the same.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.checkThis', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).siblings('.checkThis').is(':checked')) {
      $('.btnClick').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $('.btnClick').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkThis">Check me
<input type="checkbox" class="checkThis">Check me too
<button type="submit" class="btnClick" disabled="disabled">Click me</button>
```